# Как создать дополнительный способ приема платежей WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Добрый день,
В WooCommerce есть способ приёма платежей Наложенным путём (наличными при доставке - Cash on Delivery). 
Мне нужно скопировать этот способ и переименовать его на "Сертификатом при доставке".
Как это сделать без посторонних плагинов (желательно)?

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой файл /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/gateways/cod/class-wc-gateway-cod.php, он содержит платежный шлюз Cash on Delivery. Его надо взять за основу.

Просто так скопировать - вставить не получится. Куда вставить? Как обновлять потом WooCommerce? Надо делать свой платежный шлюз отдельным плагином.

Примерный код такого плагина:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: My New WooCommerce Gateway
 * Plugin URI:
 * Description: WooCommerce gateway to ....
 * Author: .....
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author URI: https://mysite.org/
 * Text Domain: woocommerce-my-gateway
 * Domain Path: /languages/
 */

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'init_my_gateway_class' );

function init_my_gateway_class() {
    if ( !class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) return;
    class WC_Gateway_COD_Renamed extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
    // здесь код класса COD, исправленный по усмотрению
    }
}

function add_my_gateway_class( $methods ) {
    $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_my_gateway';
    return $methods;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_my_gateway_class' );

function my_load_textdomain(){
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'woocommerce-my-gateway', false, dirname( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/languages/' ) );
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'my_load_textdomain');
```

Comment: После установки данного плагина возникла ошибка 500 на странице настроек WooCommerce

Comment: А вы что - вот так прямо и записали, как в ответе? ))) Я дал идею кода, а вставлять туда код класса COD, исправлять его - это довольно большая работа, которую вы должны сделать сами.

Comment: Вы задали вопрос, который не решается посторонними плагинами и не выражается в нескольких строках кода.